# Android onResume again calling onResume

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

I have an activity, where you can enter a information and it saves in db. The same activity also works as edit activity. When I want to retrieve data from db, it populates the edit text and rest of the field through "onResume" method.

Now I also have option if I want to add a picture. So when I click to add picture(Either from Gallery or Camera), it takes me to gallery or camera, and on picture select it takes me back to edit activity through onResume.

While retrieving the activity app works fine, it can also gets picture from db if I have any. Now I can retrieve data or anything from db and make any changes to edit text if I want, but when running the "onResume" again I am not able to make changes to my app..

I am just not able to figure this out.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer, I moved the my method in "onCreate"

Comment: Just when I wanted to say that. For data initialization, it's better to put inside `onCreate()` so that it will be called once. You can always refer to [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#lifecycle-states) to understand more about it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening a Camera Intent or Gallery Intent, the Gallery or the Camera comes on foreground where your activity goes to the background which calls the

```
onPause()
```

and when your Gallery or Camera activity closes, the background activity comes to the foreground and it calls the

```
onResume()
```

You can either call your other options in

```
onCreate()
```

if needed only once

and to open Camera and Gallery use

```
  startActivityForResult()
```

and receive data in

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```